# How to verify gauge invariance of an amplitude

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, gauge-invariance

I have calculated a tree level amplitude for Compton scattering (${e\left(p\right)+\gamma\left(k\right)\to e\left(p\prime\right)+\gamma\left(k\prime\right)}$):

$${
i\mathcal{M}=M_{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{*\mu}\left(k\prime\right)\epsilon^{\nu}\left(k\right)\textrm{.}
}$$

How should I go about trying to verify that it is gauge invariant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that the polarization tensors depend on the gauge choice via reference vectors (call them $q$, $q'$) Now you have to check what happen when you chance the reference vectors from $q, q'$ to some new vectors $r,r'$. The change of the vectors will lead to the new polarization vectors aquire a term proportional to its momentum $p$. 
$$\epsilon(p,r)^\mu \sim \epsilon(p,q)^\mu+p^\mu$$

The contraction of the last term with $M_{\mu\nu}$ vanishes, i.e. you have shown gauge invariance.
Do you also have to show that $M_{\mu\nu}$ contracted into one of its momenta vanishes?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks muchly for your help.